# How to separate the hover and click events using Jquery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I call a hover function to show a dialog box as tooltip, and the click function to show the same dialog box with an extra class
that is hidden on hover.

It works once but the second time the dialog box is not reflecting. It blocks the hover.

How to separate the Mouseover and Click events?

```
var clicked = false
$("izzy").observe('mouseover', function() {
     if(!clicked) {
        $('izzy').setStyle({ color: '#FFFFFF' });
     }
});

$("izzy").observe('mouseout', function() {
     if(!clicked) {
        $('izzy').setStyle({ color: '#666666' });
     }
});

$("izzy").observe('click', function() {
    clicked = true
    $('izzy').setStyle({ color: '#cccccc' });
});
```

Comment: please add snippet/jsfiddle

Comment: @KrupeshKotecha sorry, I am unable to add fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The code within `if(!clicked) {` blocke will never get executed, once the `clicked` is set to `true`. `clicked` is getting set to `true` on `click`, so once `clicked` is set to `true`, the `callback function` for `mouseover` & `mouseout` listener will not doing anything. as per the above code.

The below code should be sufficient for your desired behavior.

```
$("izzy").observe('mouseover', function() {
     $('izzy').setStyle({ color: '#FFFFFF' });
});

$("izzy").observe('mouseout', function() {
    $('izzy').setStyle({ color: '#666666' });
});

$("izzy").observe('click', function() {
    $('izzy').setStyle({ color: '#cccccc' });
});
```

---

- on `mouseover` the `color` will get set to `#fff`
- on `click` the `color` will get set to `#ccc`
- as soon as `mouseout` happens the color will get reset to `#666`
- next time, on `mouseover` the `color` will once again get set to `#fff`

Comment: @ Sarbbottam So can you please assist me to fix that issue. Where to change clicked variable again false?